# C# ASP.NET MVC read-only for data field not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am having some issues with an edit form that does not seem to work no matter what I use.

I have tried

```
[ReadOnly(true)] and [Editable(false)]
```

in the Model

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SellingPrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = true } })
```

in the View..

I have changed the controller with nothing about the field.

I have also tried changing the model to

```
{ get; private set; }
```

According to a other post on another site using the `[ReadOnly(true)]` in the model and nothing in the controller pointing to it, it should come up 'null' and it does not. It seems to give a value of 0 or what the field has in it. Depending on if I use it in the edit View or not.

This field in the table is a calculated field on the SQL side. Used only for viewing.

Below is the controller POST - 2 Versions that I have tried:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(ProductMaster productMaster)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ProductMaster prodFromDB = db.ProductMaster.Single(x => x.ProductMasterId == productMaster.ProductMasterId);

            prodFromDB.VendorId = productMaster.VendorId;
            prodFromDB.Material = productMaster.Material;
            prodFromDB.VendorRef = productMaster.VendorRef;
            prodFromDB.CreatedDate = productMaster.CreatedDate;
            prodFromDB.CreatedBy = productMaster.CreatedBy;
            prodFromDB.LastUpdated = productMaster.LastUpdated;
            prodFromDB.UpdatedBy = productMaster.UpdatedBy;
            prodFromDB.UnitOfMeasure = productMaster.UnitOfMeasure;
            prodFromDB.StandardCost = productMaster.StandardCost;
            prodFromDB.AverageCost = productMaster.AverageCost;
            prodFromDB.LastCost = productMaster.LastCost;
            prodFromDB.IsPrimary = productMaster.IsPrimary;

            var Manager = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;
            Manager.ChangeObjectState(prodFromDB, System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified);

            db.SaveChanges();

            sb.Append("Submitted");
            return Content(sb.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var key in this.ViewData.ModelState.Keys)
            {
                foreach (var err in this.ViewData.ModelState[key].Errors)
                {
                    sb.Append(err.ErrorMessage + "<br/>");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        sb.Append("Error :" + ex.Message);
    }

    return Content(sb.ToString());
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ProductMasterId,VendorId,Material,VendorRef,CreatedDate,CreatedBy,LastUpdated,UpdatedBy,UnitOfMeasure,StandardCost,AverageCost,LastCost,IsPrimary")] ProductMaster productMaster)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(productMaster).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            sb.Append("Submitted");
            return Content(sb.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var key in this.ViewData.ModelState.Keys)
            {
                foreach (var err in this.ViewData.ModelState[key].Errors)
                {
                    sb.Append(err.ErrorMessage + "<br/>");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        sb.Append("Error :" + ex.Message);
    }

    return Content(sb.ToString());
}
```

The error that I get is:

> The column "SellingPrice" cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing would be to mark the Entity property with the DatabaseGeneratedOption of Computed:

```
public class Product
{
    // ...
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public decimal SellingPrice { get; internal set; }

    // ...
}
```

The next thing would be to avoid code that sets an entity's EntityState to modified explicitly. So long as the DbContext is tracking the entity, this should be enough:

```
ProductMaster prodFromDB = db.ProductMaster.Single(x => x.ProductMasterId == productMaster.ProductMasterId);

prodFromDB.VendorId = productMaster.VendorId;
prodFromDB.Material = productMaster.Material;
prodFromDB.VendorRef = productMaster.VendorRef;
prodFromDB.CreatedDate = productMaster.CreatedDate;
prodFromDB.CreatedBy = productMaster.CreatedBy;
prodFromDB.LastUpdated = productMaster.LastUpdated;
prodFromDB.UpdatedBy = productMaster.UpdatedBy;
podFromDB.UnitOfMeasure = productMaster.UnitOfMeasure;
prodFromDB.StandardCost = productMaster.StandardCost;
prodFromDB.AverageCost = productMaster.AverageCost;
prodFromDB.LastCost = productMaster.LastCost;
prodFromDB.IsPrimary = productMaster.IsPrimary;

db.SaveChanges();
```

The reason is that lets say I have an entity with 20 columns and I update 5 of them from the view model, and only 2 of those values actually differ from the entity's current state. If I let the DbContext track the changes and just call `SaveChanges` then the resulting `UPDATE` SQL statement will be an update specifying just the columns which values actually changed.  If instead I set the `EntityState` to Modified, the `UPDATE` SQL statement will include ***all*** columns, whether I set them or not, and whether they actually changed or not. Computed columns should be ignored, but why incur the cost/risk of updating/overwriting values you don't intend to have been changed?

Comment: Perfect and thank you very much, and no I do believe that it is better to only change what needs to be changed or loaded. I was unaware that 'EntityState.Modified' did that. Was a bit confused when i saw everything in the model load when i only changed a few thing. It was on me that i did not look that up. I thought it meant what it says but on a item level. not that the model state was what it meant. However that is what Entity is, isn't it.